# Which Chinese philosophy is best for understanding other cultures?

Tags: philosophy-of-culture, chinese-philosophy

Which Chinese school of thought leads to an extension of your perspective on another culture?

Comment: You can see [Feng Youlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_Youlan) and [New Confucianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Confucianism) for attempts to adapt the traditional chinase world-view to the newly discovered Western culture.

Comment: Maybe useful [François Jullien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Jullien)'s works dedicate to understand differences between Chinese and European thought, like e.g. [A Treatise on Efficacy: Between Western and Chinese Thinking](https://books.google.it/books?id=OS_YqZhWuAsC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: As worded, the question is largely opinion-based. No traditional Chinese philosophy takes this as a major concern.